# EF loop to update with async await

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I need to update my database with about 100K records over a slow network.

I thought it might be a good idea to run them async and not have to wait for the response before I run the next one. I've got this far:

```
        private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            var customerIDs = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\customerids.txt").ToList();

            foreach (var customerID in customerIDs)
            {
                var result = await DoSomethingWithTheCustomerAsync(customerID);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }



 private static async Task<bool> DoSomethingWithTheCustomerAsync(string strCustomerid)
        {
            var customerid = int.Parse(strCustomerid);
            using (var ctx = new MyEntities())
            {

                var customer = await ctx.Customers.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CustomerID == customerid);
                customer.CustomerNotes += " updated async";
                await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
                return true;
            }
        }
```

I'd really don't want to wait for the result in the foreach-loop and then continue. I'd like to wait for all the tasks after the loop has run. I tried making a list with tasks and do Task.WaitAll(tasklist) but then the database wasn't updated.

And if this can be done, is it a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, try to do this in a single message and have the "batch processing" done on the server side. E.g., a stored procedure.

It is possible to start 100k simultaneous database operations (over 100k separate connections), but this may bring your db to its knees:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var customerIDs = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\customerids.txt").ToList();
  var updates = customerIDs.Select(id => DoSomethingWithTheCustomerAsync(id));
  var results = await Task.WhenAll(updates);
  MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realise this isn't using the EF route but, take a look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) Class. This will be more efficient to insert your rows. You can also batch them in groups of rows to make it even quicker.

Comment: not 100 - 10.000. SqlBulkCopy has overhead in setup - doign that for 100 rows is not smart. I use 60.0000 rows per update normally in a LAN.

Comment: Apologies your original post was a little ambiguous. SqlBulkCopy is to "bulk load a SQL Server table with data from another source.". If you want to bulk update you could [bulk load to a temporary table first and then Merge the data in using a stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12521692/c-sharp-bulk-insert-sqlbulkcopy-update-if-exists). The alternative would be to put your data into a Table datatype and pass it to your stored procedure in a batch. Might be worth doing a few load tests with different methods to see what works best for you.